# Calculate sum with forEach function?

Tags: javascript, foreach

I want to calculate sum with forEach array function in JavaScript. 
But I don't get what I want.

```
function sum(...args) {
  args.forEach(arg => {
    var total = 0;
    total += arg;
    console.log(total);
 });
}
sum(1, 3);
```

How to get total with forEach, or use reduce method?

Comment: Define total above forEach loop

Comment: Learn about JS scopes: https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may better use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because it is made for that kind of purpose.

It takes a start value, of if not given, it take the first two elements of the array and reduces the array literally to a single value. If the array is empty and no start value is supplied, it throws an error.

```js
function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((total, arg) => total + arg, 0);
}

console.log(sum(1, 3));
console.log(sum(1));
console.log(sum());
```

Answer (score 8):

You should put `total` **outside** forEach loop:

```
function sum(...args) {
  var total = 0;
  args.forEach(arg => {
    total += arg;
  });
  console.log(total);
}

sum(1, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the total=0; out of the loop - it is being reset to 0 on each iteration

```js
function sum(...args) {
var total = 0;
args.forEach(arg => {
  total += arg;
  console.log(total); 
 });
}
sum(1, 3); // gives 1, 4 or in other words 0+1=1 then 1+3=4
```

```
function sum(...args) {
var total = 0;
args.forEach(arg => {
  total += arg;
  console.log(total);
 });
}
sum(1, 3);
```

Comment: Why not use reduce instead of uglying up your code with this extra stuff?

Comment: How is possible to remove that first step, only result?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: While the post body mentions *reduce* as an alternative, the title still reads *Calculate sum with `forEach` function*.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount); 
}

console.log(sum(1,3));
```